# How do I SUM between a date range but return blank if there is no data?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to SUM column `N` (on sheet TRADE LOG) between a date range however if there is no data for that date range I would like the cells of column `B` on sheet STATISTICS to return a blank.

I have worked out how to sum within the date range however cannot work out how to return a blank if there is no data for that date range.

The date ranges I am using is months.

Current formula is below:

`=SUMIFS('TRADE LOG'!N:N,'TRADE LOG'!B:B,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),'TRADE LOG'!N:N,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28))`

Current worksheet(s) below:

[image: Worksheet - TRADE LOG]

Comment: Why did you include an image? What added value does it provide? Please have consideration for those that read these posts with phones. Don't add images just because you can. And when they provide added value, limit the size to the essential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a number format that returns a null string if the formula returns 0:

```
$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00;;
```

Or you can return a null string if it is `0` with the reciprocal of the reciprocal:

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/SUMIFS('TRADE LOG'!N:N,'TRADE LOG'!B:B,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),'TRADE LOG'!N:N,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28))),"")
```